# I want to send email using PHPMailer?Giving error

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
**Error:**SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

My code is:

```
<?php
require('class.phpmailer.php');
//require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//require_once("inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();// create a new object
$mail ->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail ->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2                                = messages only 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 465
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "biz.online321@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mudunuru%^&";
$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("varma.sfi123@gmail.com");
print $mail;
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Your help will be apperaciated

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

You are trying to talk SSL to a non-SSL port. Do this instead:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

I'd also recommend that you get the [latest version of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and base your code on the examples provided with it.